# Switch between content with jQuery

Tags: jquery, button, switch-statement

I need some help on this one:

I have to do something like this and my jQuery-knowledge just isn't enough :(

```
<div id="dog-button"></div>
<div id="cat-button"></div>

<div id="dog"></div>
<div id="cat"></div>
```

We have two buttons. When you click the dog-button, the dog-div should appear when you click the cat-button, the cat-div appears (on the exact spot but I guess this is just CSS). Its important, that the site loads with the dog and doesn't show just nothing. Do you have any ideas? :-(

Comment: Are the divs wrapped in anything specifically? I get the association ebtween `dog-button`/'`dog` and `cat-button`/`cat` but how do you expect to hide the divs that don't relate to the specific button being clicked?

Comment: is there only ever the 2 buttons and 2 sets of content? or will there be more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a jsfiddle of code that will work for you, however to scale you will need to do a small amount of coding (you will need to add to the $('#dog, #cat').hide(); line all the extra divs to hide):

http://jsfiddle.net/KRPZS/

```
$('div[id$="-button"]').live('click', function () {
    $('#dog, #cat').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id').replace('-button', '')).show();
});
```

Comment: LOL, awesome picture-usage :D Thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#dog-button,#cat-button").click(function() {
    var divToOpen = $(this).attr("id").replace("-button","");
    $("#dog,#cat").hide();
    $("#"+divToOpen).show();
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/uhcHV/

Comment: no reason to involve jquery in getting the id `this.id` will suffice.

Comment: **Also, note that this locks you into a button/div naming convention...**

Comment: @jondavidjohn both statement are correct. About the second, my code is related to OP code. Can choose any answer that fit his requirements :)

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="dog-button"></div>
<div id="cat-button"></div>

<div id="dog"></div>
<div id="cat" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $('#dog-button').click(function(){
            $('#cat').hide();
            $('#dog').show();
        }

        $('#cat-button').click(function(){
            $('#dog').hide();
            $('#cat').show();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it would probably be a good idea to have the '#cat' hidden in jquery as well, so it degrades gracefully when javascript is not available.

Comment: It doesn't need to be scalable to switch between two divs. If there were more than two maybe, but I think this is easiest for his case, and more readable, so he can understand it even though he isn't very familiar with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something along these lines:

HTML:

```
<div class='button' id="dog-button"></div>
<div class='button' id="cat-button"></div>

<div class='content' id="dog"></div>
<div class='content' id="cat"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#cat').hide();

    $('.button').click(function(){
        $('.content').toggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something like what you are looking for:

HTML

```
<a href='#' data-id='dog' class='button'>Dog Button</a>
<a href='#' data-id='cat' class='button'>Cat Button</a>

<div id='dog' class='animal'>Woof!</div>
<div id='cat' class='animal'>Meow!</div>
```

CSS

```
.animal{
 display:none;  
   margin: 10px;
   padding: 10px;
   border: 1px solid #f2f2f2; 
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.button').click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $('.selected').hide().removeClass('selected');
        $('#' + id).addClass('selected').show();   
    });

});
```

Check out this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KVvQV/

Hope this helps.

Bob